# Troubleshooting MSI installation issues | Windows Service | C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service built using .NET/C# and have a corresponding msi created for installing the windows service. When running the msi file, i get an error - "Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the <.exe path> .assembly. -> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information".

I'm looking for suggestions on how i can get more details on the error.
Note: I've found out what exact code when added to the C# windows service solution causes the error to occur but there are no errors generated during build/compile phase.

Issue is reproducible on the following Windows system (Win2008R2 & Windows10)

Comment: To get more details you need to run msiexec from the command line and use the /L*V option to generate an installation log file.  It will be very large.

Comment: Any alternate option ?